# Exact match with awk

Tags: awk, sed

I am trying to extract the `extension_dir` using a bash script.It works under most cases but sometimes you can get a 2 line output

`php -i | awk -F '=> ' '/extension_dir/'`

```
extension_dir => /usr/lib64/php/modules => /usr/lib64/php/modules
sqlite3.extension_dir => no value => no value
```

I want to match `extension_dir` exactly so that the result is always `/usr/lib64/php/modules`

I want only `/usr/lib64/php/modules` as output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can opt for string matching as

```
$ awk -F '=> ' '$1 == "extension_dir "' input
extension_dir => /usr/lib64/php/modules => /usr/lib64/php/modules
```

- `$1 == "extension_dir "` matches the value in the first field, `$1` with `extension_dir`

**OR**

If you want to use regular expressions, add anchors to your pattern as

```
$ awk -F '=> ' '$1 ~ /^extension_dir $/' input
extension_dir => /usr/lib64/php/modules => /usr/lib64/php/modules
```

**Edit**

You can specify the field to be printed as

```
$ awk -F '=> ' '$1 == "extension_dir "' input
/usr/lib64/php/modules 

$ awk -F '=> ' '$1 ~ /^extension_dir $/{print $2}' input
/usr/lib64/php/modules
```

- `print $2` will print the value of the second field

Comment: I want only `/usr/lib64/php/modules` as output

Comment: @user2650277 oops. missed that. Edit my answer. Hope it helps you

Comment: It surely does :) Thanks mate